# How to read XML data with $.ajax and return the value within a $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, each

For one part of our study-project we need to compare an array of Strings with a xml database. So my idea was to divide in 2 parts (because we need the compare-function twice). First I loop through the array with $.each and then I pass the value to another function that makes an ajax request to the xml, compares the value with each data in xml and if something found, it pushes it to an array which should be returned at the end.

In one function the jquery.each() is called:

```
function doSomething(){

    liste = ["test1","test32","test22"];

    $.each(liste, function(index, value){

    var checkIt = compareDataBase(value);

    if(checkIt.length>0) //do Something

    });
}
```

and this is the function that compares the value and returns an array:

```
function compareDataBase(foo){

  var lists = [];

  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "data/database/datenbank.xml",
      dataType:"xml",
      success: function(xml){

          $(xml).find('product').each(function(index, element){ 
              var current_product = $(this).text();
              if(current_product.indexOf(foo)>-1)lists.push(current_product);
          });
      },
      error: function(){

          console.log("Fehler bei Produkte auslesen");
      }
  });

  return lists;

}
```

But sadly that doesn't work. "checkIt" is always undefined because it doesnt wait for the ajax... 
I tried to use the $.when function or give the compareDataBase()-function a callback but somehow that didnt work neither (I think because
I declared it wrong)

So maybe someone knows how to make this right?

Thanks for your help!

br sebi

Comment: you should use callback handlers either to process all items async or one handler calls next when finished if a kind of synchronisation is needed. Promises can also be used (probably they will make the project more transparent as well)

Comment: thanks for your comment! but where and how can i use the callbacks to make it work? - with Promises i never worked before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use callbacks (or [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which are a variation on callbacks), the following solution example uses callbacks:

```
function compareDataBase(foo, callback){

  var lists = [];

  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "data/database/datenbank.xml",
      dataType:"xml",
      success: function(xml){

          $(xml).find('product').each(function(index, element){ 
              var current_product = $(this).text();
              if(current_product.indexOf(foo)>-1)lists.push(current_product);
          });
          // notify the callback with the result lists here
          callback(lists);
      },
      error: function(){

          console.log("Fehler bei Produkte auslesen");
      }
  });

}

function doSomething(liste, index){
    if ( index < liste.length )
    {
     compareDataBase(liste[index], function(checkIt){
          if(checkIt.length>0) //do Something
          // process next list item using callbacks
          doSomething(liste, index+1);
     });
    }
}

// start the process
doSomething(["test1","test32","test22"], 0);
```

**Note** that the example solution processes each list item only after the previous item has been processed (it kind of synchronises the callbacks, each callback will call the next one). One can remove this feature and process all asynchronously as follows:

```
// process all async
var liste = ["test1","test32","test22"];
for (var i=0; i<liste.length; i++) doSomething([liste[i]], 0);
```